# React Native - Keep app running when it's killed or closed

Tags: react-native

this question may seem duplicate, but I've searched a lot, but could not find any appropriate solution.

I need my socket connection to not break when user kills/closes app. It works when user presses the home button and apps goes to background. But connection breaks when user kills or closes the app. I need behavior like how chat apps like whatsapp literally work. So when I close the whatsapp, I can still receive new messages.

If anyone has found any solution for this, please share.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your Socket connection should run as a background task and continuously listen to stream of message events even when the app close then you can push notifications to notify the user.

https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task  provide an abstract layer for both iOS and Android

Comment: Thank you for your answer, as far as I understood, I will need to do expo eject to apply this solution right? Because it seems like I'll need to write some additional statement in android/app/src/main/java/myapp/MainApplication.java.

Comment: You don"t have to eject, Expo provides its background task package - https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/task-manager/

Comment: Expo's background task manager works when the app is backgrounded, not when the app is closed.